# How to hide elements in Jquery that have been loaded in with the .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jquery-load

I have some classes that I update with the JQuery Load Function.  When the Page First Loads I target them and hide them like this:

```
$('.classname').hide();
```

I do the ajax `load` like this:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "index.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
      $('.wrapperClass').load('index.php .wrapperClass');
      $('.classname').hide();
  },
      error: function() {

      }  
});
```

To keep it simple the html is something like this:

```
<div class="wrapperClass">
    <span class="classname">Content 1</span>
    <span class="classname">Content 2</span>
</div>
```

The problem is, everything inside of the `wrapperClass` get's reloaded fine, but the spans inside don't get hidden, they re-appear and I can't figure out how to hide them after they've been reloaded via Ajax.

Answer (score 5):

As you probably(\should) know, `load` is an ajax request, so the elements are not loaded when you're trying to hide them.

Move the code that handles the loaded content to the complete callback:

```
success: function() {  
      $('.wrapperClass').load('index.php .wrapperClass', function(){
              $('.classname').hide();              
          });
      }
```

**Full code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('.wrapperClass').load('index.php .wrapperClass', function() {
            $('.classname').hide();
        });
    },
    error: function() {

    }
});​
```

`load` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

`.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)])`

- `url` A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
- `data` A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
- `complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)` **A callback function that is executed when the request completes.**

Comment: @Talon. **That just can't be**, unless you have other problems.

Comment: Figured it out, I did have other problems, it's working now thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to stick `$('.classname').hide();` into the callback function of `.load()`. Right now, it's trying to hide the elements before they exists on the page. Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "index.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
      $('.wrapperClass').load('index.php .wrapperClass', function() {$('.classname').hide();});
  },
      error: function() {

      }  
});
```